# How to shrink a finishing activity to a rectangle

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

In my Android app, I have a floating `Activity`. It's started from outside my app using [`ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html#makeScaleUpAnimation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to scale up from an "originating" rectangle. When my `Activity` finishes, I'd like it to do the reverse of that animation: i.e. it shrinks back to that rectangle as it fades out.

I know I can get the rectangle with `getIntent().getSourceBounds()`, and I'd hoped to be able to use [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) when finishing to achieve this effect, but `overridePendingTransition()` can only accept a fixed XML resource: there doesn't seem to be a way to make that animation depend on the source bounds. Is there something else I can use to achieve this effect?

My app is for API 11+, but as it's a cosmetic effect only, I'd be satisfied with a solution that depends on a later version.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? Just come up against it myself. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried showing the activity as a dialog (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ActivityAsDialog)?

Comment: @dacongy How would that help?

Comment: I thought you want to show an activity as a rectangle, instead of fullscreen. Can you explain the effects you need from a user point of view - say I'm a user of your app, what should I see?

Comment: @dacongy The activity is already non-fullscreen, with a tinted background. When you start the activity, you see it scale up from the source rectangle (as set by the launching activity, in the `Intent`) until it reaches the correct size. What I want is that when you leave the activity, it scales back down to the same rectangle before disappearing completely.

Answer (score 8):

I don think there is a way to scale down the activity window other than the overridePendingTransition call. However this code may help:

### Scale up

ActivityOptions opts = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.scale_up, 0);
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class),opts.toBundle());

Here is the scale_up animation file:

```
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

### Scale down

Call this code from the exiting activity:

```
finish();

overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.scale_down);
```

Here is the scale_down animation file:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:duration="250"/>
</set>
```

You can vary the X and Y scale to get the desired rectangle. Hope this helps.

Comment: The above code works for api 16 and above, but you can try using the ActivityOptionsCompat from the support library.

Comment: As I said in the question, I can't set the rectangle in an XML file, because it comes from the *source bounds* of the intent.

Comment: I believe for your case you can have a a transparent activity with no title and in that have view/fragment which will actually get animated as per your need.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my last comment, here is the solution which i have tried and it works. You may have to modify to suit your requirements.

Implement a Activity with Transparent background and with no title inside the manifest:

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.example.backgroundsensor.AnimatedActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="Animated activity" />
```

and let it set the content view with a layout as :

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <View
         android:id="@+id/visibleAreaView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

The visibleAreaView is the one you will see on the screen, since activity is transparent. You can set the bounds of the view in OnCreate of the activity().

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.animated_activity);

      // set the bounds of the animateView
  }
```

Also, Override the finish method something like this:

```
boolean animateFirst=true;
@Override
public void finish() {
     if(animateFirst)
     {
         animateFirst = false;
         loadAnim();

     }else
     {
         super.finish();
     }
}

 public void loadAnim() {

    View v = findViewById(R.id.animateView);
    float x= v.getX() + v.getRight()/2;
    float y = v.getY();
    anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, x, y);
    anim.setDuration(300);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            findViewById(R.id.animateView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AnimatedActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim);

}
```